# Баг со скриптом

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Есть баг со скриптом (слайдером). Когда переходишь в другую вкладку на минуты 4, а потом назад, то слайдер быстро прогартывается столько раз, сколько он должен был прогортаться за это время.

Вот собственно сам код скрипта:

```
var image_count = 3;
var interval = 5000;
var time_out = 10;
var i = 0;
var timeout;
var opacity = 100;

function change_image() {
 opacity--;
 var j = i + 1;
 var current_image = 'img_' + i;
 if (i == image_count) j = 1;
 var next_image = 'img_' + j;
 document.getElementById(current_image).style.opacity=opacity/100;
 document.getElementById(current_image).style.filter='alpha(opacity='+opacity+')';
 document.getElementById(next_image).style.opacity=(100-opacity)/100;
 document.getElementById(next_image).style.filter='alpha(opacity='+(100-opacity)+')';
 timeout = setTimeout("change_image()", time_out);
 if (opacity==1) {
  opacity = 100;
  clearTimeout(timeout);
 }
}

setInterval (function() {i++; if (i>image_count) i=1; change_image();}, interval);
```

Comment: setInterval (function() {i++; if (i>image_count) i=1; change_image();}, interval);
Попробуйте заменить на SetTimeout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот эффект связан c тем, что браузеры лимитируют timeout и interval на неактивных вкладках, вам, лучше всего не позволять коду в setInterval увеличивать номер картинки, если opacity<100

```
setInterval (function() {if (opacity<100) return;i++; if (i>image_count) i=1; change_image();}, interval);
```

> > прогортаться

где вы взяли это слово ? :)

Comment: @eicto заметил еще более крутую фишку: сделайте неактивную вкладку, потом сделайте неактивным окно браузера в windows и таймер еще медленнее будет работать :)

Comment: Спасибо огромное тебе добрый человек)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).